# Function that returns the number of characters in a C type string (\0)

Tags: c

I would like to create a function that returns the number of characters in a C character string (with \0) with UTF-8 characters. I know the principle of encoding with the first byte which sets the number of bytes for a character, but I don't see how I can go about it ?
In fact, I think the function should convert each character to bytes and the high bits should tell me the number of bytes per character so I can count the number of real characters that make up the UTF-8 string in C format (\0).

My string contains multiple characters.
I can't turn characters into bytes and find in the first byte how many bytes make a character.

Comment: Why doesn’t it answer your question? The answer there contains a function that counts UTF-8 code points.

Comment: An UTF-8 C-string is composed of `char` elements, and each one will contain one byte. If you are sure that the string contains valid UTF-8, a simple way would be to count the characters, just ignoring the continuation bytes, saying any byte having `10` in its highest order bits. Exactly what the suggested duplicate does... If it does not answer your question you really should explain why.

Comment: Sorry, that answers my question well.

Comment: This answer answers my question. Sorry

Comment: Another duplicate candidate: [How to count characters in a unicode string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298059/how-to-count-characters-in-a-unicode-string-in-c)